# Bounds on Tamagawa numbers of reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over a number field $k$. Weil's conjecture on Tamagawa numbers (now a theorem) tells us that the Tamagawa number $\tau(G)$ of $G$ is 1 if $G$ is semisimple and simply-connected. Are there known bounds for $\tau(G)$ for the general case?

Presumably one might be able to use the formula $\tau(G) = |\text{Pic}(G)|/|\text{Sha}(G)|$ and try to estimate the numerator, but I am not familiar with the literature in this respect.

Comment: The formula you quote for $\tau(G)$ seems to apply directly to a maximal torus of $G$.    In any case, this kind of formula does lead to a sort of upper bound for reductive $G$: see appendix 2 by Takashi Ono (father of the number theorist Ken Ono) in the 1982 version of the 1958-59 IAS lectures by Weil: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=670072 (and note the very large number of MathSciNet references to later work on Tamagawa numbers, including Bourbaki Seminar lectures etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the formula is correct, see Sansuc, J.-J. Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres. J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80, (10.1.2).

In the extreme cases (when G is semisimple or a torus) there are formulas for ${\rm Pic}(G)$ in Lemma 6.9 of Sansuc's paper.
Namely, when $G$ is semisimple with fundamental group $B=\pi_1(G_\bar k)$, we have
$${\rm Pic}(G)=X^*(B)^\Gamma,$$
where $X^*$ denotes the character group and $\Gamma={\rm Gal}(\bar k/k)$.
It follows that the order of the Picard group is bounded by the order of the fundamental group of $G_{\bar k}$.
When $G$ is a torus, we have
$${\rm Pic}(G)=H^1(k, X^*(G)).$$

For a general reductive group $G$, set
$G^{\rm ss}=[G,G]$ and $G^{\rm tor}=G/G^{\rm ss}$,
then for the semisimple part of $G$ we obtain $$\#{\rm Pic}(G^{\rm ss})\le\#\pi_1(G^{\rm ss}_{\bar k})$$
and for the toric part we obtain
$$\#{\rm Pic}(G^{\rm tor})=\# H^1(k,X^*(G)).$$
From the short exact sequence
$$ 1\to G^{\rm ss}\to G\to G^{\rm tor}\to 1$$
we obtain an exact sequence
$${\rm Pic}\ G^{\rm tor}\to{\rm Pic}\ G\to {\rm Pic}\ G^{\rm ss},$$
see Sansuc's paper, Corollary 6.11. We obtain the following bound:
$$\#\tau(G)\ \le\ \#{\rm Pic}(G)\ \le \# H^1(k,X^*(G))\cdot \#\pi_1(G^{\rm ss}_{\bar k}).$$

Comment: For a general reductive group, see formula (2.4.1) in the paper of Robert E. Kottwitz "Stable trace formula: cuspidal tempered terms", Duke Math. J. 51 (1984), no. 3, 611–650.